# How to resize an input image from 800x600 to 416x416 using C/C++ code and image processing algorithms? What could be the scale factor to resize?

Tags: c++, image, opencv, image-processing

As mentioned in the question. I want to resize an image from 800x600 to 416x416 dimensions. How to find out the scale factor for those dimensions? and how can I resize using scaleBilinear / scaleBicubic kernels?

Please help me, Thanks in advance.

Comment: `cv::resize(img, img2, cv::Size(416, 416));`

Comment: interpolation options (bi-linear, bi-cubic) are detailed in the docs for that API. I'm sure you know of https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/